# Entitlement for writing to /Volumes in Sandbox

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox

I have an app which monitors the /Volumes directory for changes and lets users access the mounted volumes which appear in the directory.

To my surprise many methods like NSWorkspace.mountedLocalVolumePaths, NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification notification and FSEventStreamCreate returned without error and I was able to monitor the directory like before but writing to any sub-directories of /Volumes is not working and adding the file URL to a pasteboard is failing with __CFPasteboardIssueSandboxExtensionForPath errors.

Is there an entitlement I need for this or is this strictly forbidden to gain write access to volumes unless the user selects them in a dialog or drags/drops?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such entitlements, but you can ask the user to give you permissions on /Volumes and save those permissions using [Security-Scoped Bookmarks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16).

Comment: Good idea. I implemented this solution and it's only a minor annoyance to the user. ;) Thanks!